# AutoHotkey Run command issue in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, autohotkey

this is my first time on such a prestidigious site, so please welcome me by assisting me. I am doing independent development and am primarily a music designer. So that is why I may not sound like a real pro coder but nevertheless truly love creating my music through automative processes.

My present issue is this:
Windows 8.1 Pro
AutoHotkey 1.0.48.5 32bit (running as Admin)

Everytime I attempt to use the command 'RUN' with an .ahk target, I get the expected result except that the .ahk residing folder is opened by MS Explorer. I suspect that something like the fact that AutoHokey is an unsigned app, windows does not want it to run flawlessly. I am now trying a number of Administrative Tool Services disabling, but with no success yet.

`RUN C\:XZN\Mecanisms\AnyAHK_script.ahk
    ;;or
    RUN AnyAHK_script.ahk, C\:XZN\Mecanisms
    ;;or
    RUN C\:XZN\Mecanisms\BactchfileLaunchingAboveScript.bat
    ;;or
    RUN AnyAHK_script.ahk, C\:XZN\Mecanisms`

Would there be a workaround this at the OS settings level or another way to run/start an .ahk file?

I tried the 'Comspec' approach as well as running an .ahk from within a batchfile, but the .ahk always get intercepted whenever it contains a 'RUN' command requesting an .ahk target.

Thanks.

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of AHK first, [here](http://ahkscript.org/download/), and post a sample of your code if possible, especially the `Run` command.

Comment: Yes I'll post some sample code of this issue in a couple of days and will report her about both my WIN764Pro and WIN81Pro new code behavior as both build will run uptodate AHK versions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using outdated version of AutoHotkey which is more than 5 years old. Always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!

Comment: You are so right, probably ported the same version I successfully utilized on WINXP32Pro into WIN764Ultimate, also successful, and from there porting to WIN81Pro unsuccessfully. I am now building a WIN764Pro on the WIN81Pro laptop but kept both OS on 2 different HDD so I will be able run uuptodate AHK as you specified. Will give a repport here in a couple of days. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try if you only have this problem on win 8 is to Enable interaction with administrative programs http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/70449-enable-interaction-with-administrative-programs/

That script modifies the executable file's embedded manifest, then creates and installs a self-signed certificate and uses it to sign the file. The executable will not run on any other system, unless you install the certificate used to sign the file.

But lets see some script code that way we have something to test with and can better help you out...

Comment: blackholyman, I did check a bit that approach a week ago and that is when I started to think that I really should get in line with the project of switching to WIN764 so as to get back the audio designing ASAP before waisting too much time with Windows world of 'permissions'. And the morning before I started to proceed onto WIN764, a couple of cool techs told me that Windows 10 should be officially introduced in about 12 months. Maybe Windows 8 is something like Vista. Never touched that.

Comment: Where 'spicounter_XRTLT_Launch.exe' is compiled from 'spicounter_XRTLT_Launch.ahk'. I also tried to have a batchfile, commented line, to launch this compiled .exe but with the same behavior. But at the moment I do not have the WIN8 hdd to test that. Essentially, one script launches another script an so on, but on WINXPPro 32bit and WIN764Pro 64bit I am always successful.

Also I must tell @Sidola that on another 2year old machine running WIN764Ultimate I am running Autohotkey_L. I just did go on the wrong website to get the ""latest"" AHK (!!!) for my all new WIN8 install.